# Show that if $f:X \to Y$ is injective and final, then $f$ is initial

Tags: general-topology

> Show that if $f:X \to Y$ is injective and final, then $f$ is initial.

So Im having kind of a hard time in incorporating the concepts of *initial topology* and *final topology*, and I think this exercise (which Im not being able to solve) is kind of crucial.

To prove that $f$ is initial, I take a topological space $Z$ and a function $h: Z \to X$ and I want to show that $h$ is continuous, if and only if $f \circ h:Z \to Y$ is continuous.

In one direction its easy: If $h$ is continuous, then, since $f$ is final, in particular, $f$ is continuous, and therefore the composition $f \circ h$ is continuous.

However, in the reverse direction, if $f \circ h$ is continuous, im not being able to show that $h$ is continuous:

Since $f$ is final, we have two equivalent conditions that are true:

1) Given $U \subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, then $U$ is open

2) For any given topological space $Z$ and for any function $g:Y \to Z$ then $g$ is continuous if and only if $g \circ f$ is continuous.

So I tried to solve the problem using both conditions, and got nowhere.

Can anyone give me a hint/explanation/suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint, since $f$ is injective, for each $U \subseteq X$ we have $U = f^{-1}[f[U]]$. Hence if $U$ is open, so is $f[U]$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is injective and $f(X,\mathcal{T}_X) \to (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ is final.

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be another topology on $X$ such that $f:(X,\mathcal{T}) \to (Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$ is continuous.
Let $O$ be in $\mathcal{T}_X$. Then $f^{-1}[f[O]] = O$ (As $f$ is 1-1) and so by $f$ being final, $f[O] \in \mathcal{T}_Y$, and so by continuity of $f$, $O = f^{-1}[f[O]] \in \mathcal{T}$. So $\mathcal{T}_X \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ and so $\mathcal{T}_X$ is the coarsest topology that makes $f$ continuous (as a map to $(Y, \mathcal{T}_Y)$), and so $f$ is initial.